# What is the correct way to publish a message over JMS topic which has been injected in an EJB from a Netty event loop?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms

I have a `@Singleton` EJB which is started at `@Startup`, this bean listens to multicast traffic using netty. And what I would like to do is, on receipt of a message over multicast, send a JMS message on an injected topic (so on Wildfly, with JMS 2.0, I have the following:)

```
  @Resource(lookup = "java:/jboss/exported/jms/topic/appUpdates")
  private Topic appUpdate;

  @Inject
  private JMSContext context;
```

I know there are no problems with the topic and publishing a message if I have a `@Schedule`d function in the ejb, I can happily create a publisher and send a message. However attempt to publish JMS message from the netty event loop context results in:

> 2:10:34,441 ERROR [stderr] (nioEventLoopGroup-0-1)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   java:comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry 12:10:34,441 ERROR
>   [stderr] (nioEventLoopGroup-0-1)  at
>   org.jboss.as.messaging.deployment.JMSContextProducer$JMSContextWrapper.getDelegate(JMSContextProducer.java:217)

So my question is, what is the correct way to publish from the let's say *non-jboss context* (Netty event loop) to the JMS topic?

EDIT: I see now that I'm actually breaking the EJB spec by trying to get my bean to listen to the multicast traffic, so, now the question is, short of writing a resource adapter, is there any simpler way to do this?

(Server: Wildfly 8.2.0.Final using standalone-full.xml config)

Comment: I have a similar problem.  I'm getting messages from a (ZeroMQ) socket in a thread created in a singleton's PostConstruct method.  When I try and create JMS message (JmxContext.createMapMessage()) i get a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry exception.

Comment: @Dobbo, see my edit, it's actually *not allowed* to use an EJB (and it's state) from within a context that is not *managed* by the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer is crap - the **correct** way to do this is to create a JCA Resource Adapter - which I ended up creating in the end. Now I don't need the JMS topic anymore as my MDBs listen directly to the events from the *inbound* connection.

The only complication is that there is little documentation on how to do this with the 1.7 spec (using annotations), so one has to look at the xml config used for 1.5 etc. and apply appropriate annotations.